# Blank CardView is repeating in a recyclerView in a fragment

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

Picture of the app:

[image]

I am a beginner, I don't know how to fix this bug.
The Images should come one after the other, the width should be *Match_Parent*.
But after each image there is a cardView Space. I don't the reason behind that. 
I have used LinearLayoutMangaer to populate the recyclerView. First I tried with the GridLayoutManager the result was same.

[Image of the View]

**fragmentWall.java**

```
public class fragmentWall extends Fragment {

private String title;
private int page;
public DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

ImageView imageView;
public static fragmentWall newInstance(int page, String title) {
    fragmentWall fragmentp = new fragmentWall();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentp.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentp;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_wall, container, false);
    //TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvpopular);
    //tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagerow);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewWall);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return view;
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, ImageViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, ImageViewHolder>(
            image_details.class,
            R.layout.rowwall,
            ImageViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ImageViewHolder viewHolder, final image_details model, int position) {

            //viewHolder.setDate(model.getdate().toString());
            viewHolder.setImage(getContext(),model.geturl());
            viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String url= null;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SetWallpaper.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", model.geturl());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL is: "+model.geturl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };


    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutWall);
    }


    public void setImage (Context ctx, String Url){
        ImageView post_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.imagerow);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(Url).into(post_image);
    }
}
}
```

**fragment_fragment_wall.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper.fragmentWall">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewWall">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**rowwall.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This change `LinearLayout` Height to `wrap_content`

**rowwall.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of your rowwall.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```